# Фоновый процесс

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

Задачи таковы:

1) Создать процесс, который в фоне увеличивает некое число на единицу за определенный интервал времени.

2) Создать процесс, который в фоне будет слушать некое сообщение (например, нам с сервера пришло уведомление, и мы должны показать его пользователю) 
Я ознакомился со [статьей](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/apps/mt299100.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-3), но это не помогло. Установка триггеров не то, что мне надо.

P.S. приложение работает на архитектуре p2p

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Для получения ответа поясните, в чем именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д. Приведите пример кода.

Comment: Проблема в отсутствии понятия как это реализовать (какой код писать).

Comment: В общем, вопрос по архитектуре, так? Что вы вообще пытаетесь написать? Не понимаю зачем вам для описанных задач UWP.

Comment: Что-то на подобии мессенджера. Нужно выводить уведомление, когда пришло новое сообщение. Если это важно, то обмен происходит по протоколу P2P.

Answer (score 1):

1) Можно реализовать данное требование при помощи класса Timer из .NET. http://www.dotnetperls.com/timer

2) Для этих целей можно было бы использовать веб-сервис(SOAP или REST). Сервер посылает запрос в вашу программу, а она реагирует. Ну или может быть [SignalR](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-server)`

**UPDATE**

2) Так как UWP-приложения могут уходить в Suspend-Mode, то необходимо, что бы сообщения от сервера оставались доступными, в любое время. Я бы реализовал данную функцию при помощи Queue. К примеру Rabbit MQ или Azure Storage Queue. Сервер посылает сообщения о каком либо действии в Queue, а ваше приложение в определенных интервалах и после выхода из Suspend'a могло бы забирать сообщения из очереди и обрабатывать их.

Comment: Это по идее не покатит для UWP: процесс может быть уведён в suspend.

Comment: @VlaD: пардон, не знал таких подробностей, сейчас переправлю ответ.

Comment: Приложение ВКонтакте как-то работает свернуто. Также как и приложение почта. Какие-то танцы с бубном.

Comment: Только что проверил, приложение вк продолжает выводить уведомления даже будучи закрытым.